# Mavenized Seam 2.3.1.Final project get FileNotFoundException while trying to access a simple view

Tags: java, maven, jboss, seam, seam2

When I access for example `src/main/webapp/home.xhtml` the browser displays it with no problem, but when trying to access `src/main/webapp/views/example.xhtml` get the following:

```
02:04:27,513 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myproject].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-16) The Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw an exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException
at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache._getLastModified(DefaultFaceletCache.java:172) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.access$000(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:82) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:256) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:366) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:774) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195) [urlrewritefilter-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159) [urlrewritefilter-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141) [urlrewritefilter-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90) [urlrewritefilter-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:406) [urlrewritefilter-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>myproject</name>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam-debug</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam-ioc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam-pdf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                <groupId>ant</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
                <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>knowledge-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-templates</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>myproject</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<!-- SEAM -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- URL REWRITING -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- JSF -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<!-- RICHFACES -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- FONTS -->
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>otf</extension>
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ttf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Can anybody help me, I would like to organize my project using sub folders under my `src/main/webapp` source folder.

Comment: Are there any Java source files in this module? Should this be a "skinny war"?

Comment: Source files are under `src/main/java` package, excluding *.java is set for `src/main/resources` package. I don't need to have sources in my war just the .class files. Do you think there's an issue with that?